# Should Zookeeper be installed seperately for Kafka Manager?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, yahoo-kafka-manager

In Kafka-manager github [page](https://github.com/yahoo/kafka-manager) it is written that:

> The minimum configuration is the zookeeper hosts which are to be used
>   for kafka manager state. This can be found in the application.conf
>   file in conf directory. The same file will be packaged in the
>   distribution zip file; you may modify settings after unzipping the
>   file on the desired server.
>
> kafka-manager.zkhosts="my.zookeeper.host.com:2181" You can specify
>   multiple zookeeper hosts by comma delimiting them, like so:
>
> kafka-manager.zkhosts="my.zookeeper.host.com:2181,other.zookeeper.host.com:2181"
>   Alternatively, use the environment variable ZK_HOSTS if you don't want
>   to hardcode any values.
>
> ZK_HOSTS="my.zookeeper.host.com:2181"

So my questions are:

1. Does Kafka-manager already contain Zookeeper when I download it?
2. Should I install Zookeeper for Kafka Manager seperately or use already installed Zookeeper used for Apache Kafka?
3. How many Zookeper instances are required for Kafka-Manager?
4. If I should install Zookeeper dedicated to Kafka-Manager, is it okey to install it in the same machine which Kafka-Manager installed or should I create another Zookeeper cluster in different machines?

I wonder what is the best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does Kafka-manager already contain Zookeeper when I download it?

No. It's just a web application. You can use the Zookeeper that's used by Kafka, though

That should answer the rest of your question...